Symfony 3 -> 4 service is private
I am currently updating an old application from Symfony 3.4. I get the following deprecation:
User Deprecated: The "security.encoder_factory" service is private, getting it from the container is deprecated since Symfony 3.2 and will fail in 4.0. You should either make the service public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency injection instead.
I get the same problem for another service: fos_user.change_password.form.factory
Here is my Controller, which I use:
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Form\UserType;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\UniqueConstraintViolationException;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;


class ProfileAdminController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("/profile", name="editProfile")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();

    if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
    }

    $groups = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Group')->findAll();
    $formUser = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user, array('groups' => $groups, 'type' => 'profile'));

    /** Passwort edit */

     $formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.change_password.form.factory');
    //$formFactory = $changecontroller;

    $formPw = $formFactory->createForm();
    $formPw->setData($user);

    /** User edit */

    $formUser->handleRequest($request);

    if ($formUser->isSubmitted() && $formUser->isValid()) {
        // 3) save the User!
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        try {
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
        }
        catch(UniqueConstraintViolationException $e)
        {
            $this->addFlash(
                'danger',
                'Ein eindeutiges Attribut wurde doppelt vergeben!'
            );
        }

        $this->addFlash(
            'info',
            'Angaben erfolgreich geändert!'
        );
    }
    else if ($formUser->isSubmitted() && !$formUser->isValid())
    {
        $validator = $this->get('validator');

        return $this->render('administration/profile/edit.html.twig', array(
            'formPw' => $formPw->createView(),
            'formUser' => $formUser->createView(),
            'errors' => $validator->validate($user),
        ));
    }

    /** Passwort edit */

    $formPwPostData = $request->request->get('fos_user_change_password_form');

    /** Check if current password is correct */
    $factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
    $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($user);
    $pwCorrect = ($encoder->isPasswordValid($user->getPassword(),$formPwPostData['current_password'],$user->getSalt())) ? true : false;

I cannot fix this issue. Could anyone help?
BR, Andreas

As a short term fix you can change the default to public in the services.yaml file. But since you are upgrading an old app I would assume you plan on keeping it around for awhile. So you may as well accept the fact that you need to adjust your code to inject dependencies instead of puling from the container. You have plenty more fun ahead of you besides this rather minor issue.  Might be easier to just start with a fresh 7.x project and then start porting code.

Making a fresh project is not really needed if the project isn't too big. There are a few step ahead which are harder than others but if you know symfony enough it isn't so hard. The annoying part are mostly the switch to the symfony flex architecture, eventual composer dependencies that are outdated and the new authenticator system in Symfony 5.3. A big part of the rest can be done with Rector.

I think I will recreate the project with Symfony 7, thank you!
